# Upload file distant server

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload

I'm using Formidable Pro and I create a hook to get all the data after the submit (Don't want to pay the addon API). I modify the action of the form to go to my PHP script after submitting. I just have a problem now, the form is used also to send images and PDF files.

I try to move the images and PDF files after the submitting, with move_uploaded_file but nothing works. I display the infos of  $_FILES and I have this infos :

```
array(
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => compte_rendu_12-12-16.pdf
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => application/pdf
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /tmp/phpHCenke
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 176072
            )

    )
```

Here is my PHP code :

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file70'][0]['name']);
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file70'][0]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Upload with success";
} else {
    echo "Upload error";
}
```

I always have the message "upload error".

Any idea ?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file70']['tmp_name'][0]`

Comment: ['tmp_name'] isn't an array? @RiggsFolly

Comment: @DevNiels It is in the dump that the OP is showing us. [See the manual for Uploading Multiple Files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh you're right, I'm dumb ahah. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $FILES array should be referenced as

```
$_FILES['file70']['name'][0]
```

when multiple files are being uploaded